# Back Referencing Django models

Tags: django, django-models

I've 3 models.

```
class ShipmentWeightMapping(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add = True)
    shipment_id = models.ForeignKey('Shipment')



class ShipmentDimensionMapping(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add = True)
    length = models.IntegerField()
    breadth = models.IntegerField()
    height = models.IntegerField()
    shipment_id = models.ForeignKey('Shipment')




class Shipment(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    job_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    weights = models.ForeignKey('ShipmentWeightMapping')#backref
    dimensions = models.ForeignKey('ShipmentDimensionMapping')#backref
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add = True, db_index = True)
```

I want to backref `weights` and `dimensions` to their respective classes, so that when I query Shipment model for `id=1`, I should get `length`, `breadth` and `height` from `ShipmentDimensionMapping` and `weight` from `ShipmentWeightMapping` without querying `ShipmentDimensionMapping` and `ShipmentWeightMapping` separately.

For eg:- Currently I do like this.

To get Shipment Details for `id = 1`, I do the following.

```
dimension_obj = ShipmentDimensionMapping.objects.filter(shipment_id = 1)[0]
length = dimension_obj.length
#similarly for other details in ShipmentDimensionMapping

weight_obj = ShipmentWeightMapping.objects.filter(shipment_id = 1)[0]
weight = weight_obj.weight
#similarly for other details in ShipmentWeightMapping

shipment_obj = Shipment.objects.filter(shipment_id = 1)[0]
job_id = shipment_obj.job_id
#similarly for other details in Shipment
```

Is there any way in which I only query `shipment_obj` and I get details of `ShipmentWeightMapping` and `ShipmentDimensionMapping`?

Also, I always use the result at zeroth index `[0]` to get the result. Although the result returned always contains only 1 item, still I need to do `[0]`. How can I avoid this as well?

Answer (score 0):

Since weight and dimension data are on other tables, you can't get them without querying these two tables.

For the second question, if you know there's only one entry, you can do:

```
shipment_obj = Shipment.objects.get(id=1)
```

BTW; you don't have to add ID values explicitly since they are called `id` in your code as well which is by default in Django.

Comment: No. I've seen people using `select_related` for my 1st query, but I dont know how to use them. Thanks for the 2nd.

Comment: What do you mean by this statement `BTW; you don't have to add ID values explicitly since they are called id in your code as well which is by default in Django.` I didnt get it.

Comment: You can use select_related to follow FK tables, sure, I didn't think you were asking about this. For ID fields, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/ There's no ID field even though Django creates one.

Comment: So, how can I use `select_related` in my case?

Comment: First remove `_id` from `shipment_id` foreign keys (because `_id` is automatically added to the DB field) and then try this: ShipmentDimensionMapping.objects.select_related("shipment").get(shipment=1)